# Strange desktop on login requries ESC to see icons etc. 23.10

Tags: nvidia, gnome-shell

I had some glitch with my Nvidia driver update and various things seemed to have been reset. Now when I log in, the desktop appears like this, and I have to hit ESC to see the normal Ubuntu desktop with icons an dock, etc.:

[image]

Does anyone know why?